# Check in PHP if form was submitted when used javascript to submit the form

Tags: php

I have this code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="selectForm" id="selectForm" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" form="selectForm" />CheckBox
    </form>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" onclick="document.selectForm.submit();" />
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            echo "Submitted";
        } else {
            echo "Not submitted";
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I can not detect if the form was submitted. I would like to modify the PHP code and not the html, if possible.

Previously I had my Submit type input inside the form and it worked, but now that it is outside and I use JavaScript to do the submit it does not work.
How can I detect if the form is submitted ?

Comment: Try a `var_dump($_POST)` and see the difference between displaying the form page and displaying the result after submitting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$_POST['submit']` will no longer exist, since the submit button is no longer part of the form.  Instead we can check the [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
   echo 'Submitted';
}
```

Also, if you leave the form's action attribute blank, it will submit to the current page:

```
<form name="selectForm" id="selectForm" action="" method="post">
```

---

**Update:**

Add a hidden field with the name of your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="formname" value="selectForm" />

<?php
if(isset($_POST['formname'])) {
    echo $_POST['formname'] . ' submitted';
}
?>
```

Comment: I can not use this because I have another form in the page that uses the method post.

Comment: Definitely do not think it deserves a `-1`, since how were we supposed to know from your original question?  Anyways, I updated with another solution.

Comment: Thanks it is working great, sorry if I did not gave all the details at first, but I am quite new to web programming.

Comment: The hidden field is the best option. It doesn't require a value though, just the name is enough.